# Installing python 2.7.8 on Linux

Tags: python, installation

I am trying to install python 2.7.8 on CentOS 6.5 with the following command

```
./configure --prefix=/sw/python/python-2.7.8/
```

followed by

```
make
```

which gave the following message at the end

```
   Python build finished, but the necessary bits to build these modules were not found:_
tkinter           bsddb185           dl imageop            sunaudiodev
```

How can I install these bits? 
Thanks.

Comment: Do you really need to? Are you going to be building Tk apps?

Comment: Nope, I am just trying to install python 2.7.8 in a non standard path `(/sw/python/python-2.7.8)` which I have done successfully in the past for 2.7.5.

Comment: I tried the same command with `--enable-share` and it worked this time! I think I forgot to add `make install` the first time around at the end, my bad :)!